# Error al imprimir los elementos de un Array (Java)

Tags: java

¡Hola!, buenas a todos. Estoy creando este código donde un usuario puede ingresar números (están dentro de un arreglo), cambiarlos y eliminarlos. Tengo un método que elimina el numero seleccionado por el usuario, el problema es que cuando elimina un numero y este quiere imprimir nuevamente la lista de los números restantes, salta este tipo de errores:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at Numero_Dos.getNumero(Numero_Dos.java:49)
    at TestNumero.main(TestNumero.java:59)
C:\Users\RaulPC\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 minute 35 seconds)
```

En case 4, es donde si elimino un numero, salta el error automáticamente. Ya busque distintas maneras de arreglarlo pero no consigo nada :(

**Mi codigo es el siguiente:**

### CLASE MAIN

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestNumero {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        Numero_Dos numP;
        int opc1, n, j=0, k = 0, numero = 0, dato = 0;
        System.out.println("¿Cuantos numeros tendra el programa?");
        n = leer.nextInt();
        numP = new Numero_Dos(n);
        do {
            System.out.println("1.- Alta de numero");
            System.out.println("2.- Cambio de numero");
            System.out.println("3.- Eliminar un numero");
            System.out.println("4.- Imprimir numeros");
            System.out.println("5.- Salir");
            opc1 = leer.nextInt();
            switch (opc1) {
                case 1:
                    if (j<n) {
                        System.out.println("Ingrese el numero por favor");
                        numero=leer.nextInt();
                        if(!numP.numeroRepetido(numero)){
                            numP.setNumero(k++, numero);
                            j++;
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("Este numero ya esta repetido, ingresa otro");
                        }
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("No puedes agregar mas numeros");
                        }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    int pos;
                    System.out.println("Ingrese el numero que desea cambiar");
                    dato=leer.nextInt();
                    if ((pos = numP.buscarNum(dato)) == -1) {
                        System.out.println("¡El dato no existe en el arreglo!");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Ingrese el nuevo numero");
                        numero=leer.nextInt();
                        numP.setNumero(pos, numero);
                        System.out.println("Ingresando numeros.....");
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Ingrese que numero desea eliminar");
                    dato=leer.nextInt();
                    if ((pos = numP.buscarNum(dato)) == -1) {
                        System.out.println("¡El dato no existe en el arreglo!");
                    } else {
                        numP.borrarNumero(numero);
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                        System.out.println("Los numeros son: "+ numP.getNumero(i));
                    }
                    break;
            }
        } while (opc1 < 5);
    }
}
```

### CLASE NUMERO

**Aquí el array se crea**

```
public class Numero_Dos {

    private int arrayN[];

    Numero_Dos(int numero) {
        arrayN = new int[numero];
    }

    public void setNumero(int i, int numero) {
        arrayN[i] = numero;
    }

    public boolean numeroRepetido(int numero) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayN.length; i++) {
            if (arrayN[i] == numero) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int buscarNum(int dato) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayN.length; i++) {
            if (dato == arrayN[i]) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    public void borrarNumero(int posicion) {
    //crear un nuevo arreglo de longitud arrayN -1
    int nuevoArreglo[] = new int[arrayN.length -1];
    //recorrer arreglo anterior
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayN.length - 1; i++) {
        //si i es igual o mayor a la posición tomar el siguiente elemento
        if(i >= posicion){
           nuevoArreglo[i] = arrayN[i + 1];
        }else{
        //tomar elemento en i
        nuevoArreglo[i] = arrayN[i];
        }
    }
    //reemplazar arreglo anterior con el nuevo arreglo
    arrayN = nuevoArreglo;
}

    public int getNumero(int i) {
        return arrayN[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando borres el número también ajusta la variable n porque ahora el arreglo solo tiene n - 1 elementos:

```
if ((pos = numP.buscarNum(dato)) == -1) {
      System.out.println("¡El dato no existe en el arreglo!");
} else {
     numP.borrarNumero(numero);
    // actualizar variable n que indica la cantidad de elementos 
    // en el arreglo
     n--;
  }
```

Comment: ¡Hola!, gracias por responder. Intentare arreglar este código con todos sus consejos :)

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es al momento de imprimir, ya que recorres el arreglo desde 0 a n, y n es el valor que tiene el arreglo al inicio por ello si eliminas algo el tamaño del arreglo disminuye pero n no, y por eso te lanza el error `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` ya que el arreglo no tiene ese tamaño original.
Te recomiendo que en la clase Numero tengas una función que te devuelva el tamaño actual del arreglo `arrayN` algo así:

```
    public int getSize() {
    return arrayN.length;
}
```

y finalmente en el `case 4:` que tenga :

```
case 4:
                for (int i = 0; i < numP.getSize(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("Los numeros son: "+ numP.getNumero(i));
                }
                break;
```

Comment: ¡Hola!, antes que nada gracias por responder :)

Answer (score 0):

Inicialmente Creas un array con la cantidad de números que especifica por consola el cual guardas en la variable n , pero luego al eliminar un numero , lo que haces es crear un nuevo array de menor tamaño sin un item y nunca actualizas la variable n por eso al intentar imprimir los números el tamaño del array es menor a la variable n y tratas de acceder a un item que no existe eso te provoca el error si haces n=n-1; ya el código no explotara ,claro no se si realmente el resultado es el efecto que quieres lograr.

```
case 3:
                    System.out.println("Ingrese que numero desea eliminar");
                    dato = leer.nextInt();
                    if ((pos = numP.buscarNum(dato)) == -1) {
                        System.out.println("¡El dato no existe en el arreglo!");
                    } else {
                        numP.borrarNumero(dato);
                        n=n-1;
                    }
                    break;
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Si la repuesta te sirvió puedes marcarla como correcta